# Can't verify a modal is showing with Selenium in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, asp.net-core, selenium-chromedriver

I'm making some automated tests with Selenium in C#. It's an ASP.NET MVC Core 3 application, using xUnit for the Unit Tests and we are using Bootstrap as the UI framework. I have a problem with verifying that a modal is showing on screen.

When I run this test:

```
// HomePageAutomatedUITests.cs
[Fact]
public void Try_Open_Arkivskaber_Modal()
{
    _page.ClickArkivskaberNyButton();
    string modalValue = _page.GetArkivskaberModalAttribute("class");
    Assert.Contains("show", modalValue);
}
```

It always fails, telling me that the Assert.Contains() is never true. The Class string is normally `modal fade` but when the button is pressed its supposed to add the class "show" so it becomes `modal fade show`. This works when a user does it on the website, but for some reason I can't make it work in this test. The test tells me that the "modalValue" reads `modal fade` so it is at least reading the correct place.

The `_page` variable is a Page Object Model and the following two properties and methods are used in the test:

```
// HomePage.cs
private IWebElement ArkivskaberNyButton => _driver.FindElement(By.Id("arkivskaber-ny"));
public void ClickArkivskaberNyButton() => ArkivskaberNyButton.Click();

private IWebElement ArkivskaberModalWindow => _driver.FindElement(By.Id("opretArkivskaber"));
public string GetArkivskaberModalAttribute(string attrName) => ArkivskaberModalWindow.GetAttribute(attrName);
```

I have checked the id `arkivskaber-ny` I am passing is correct.

I'm running all the tests I do Headless using the Chrome Driver. What might be wrong here?

Comment: Are you missing Sychronisation?   - you click the button and get the value as fast as your test can run. It's likely that the "show" doesn't appear until after you've clicked. Quickest way to check is to stick a breakpoint  the line where you do your click, step over it, manually wait a second then step over the getattribute. See if that returns the expected value  (if not - debug the web page in the open session)  (if yes, add a dynamic wait with webdriverwait)  -  give it a go and let us know, i can add more detail if needed

Comment: @RichEdwards I was just about to post a self-response to this post as an answer. It is because I don't wait, as you suspect, but I couldn't figure out how to make the driver wait. But I have since found out and will post my answer below.

Comment: No worries mate - glad you solved it :-)    FYI - webdriverwait is standard thing in the selenium world. The Support package you added was removed from c# selnium project a year or two ago and it's now supported as a separate project. It's always been kept up to date, no reason to believe it won't be in the future - but they're relatively easy to write yourself (in a terrible note format):  ```public void WaitForElementToBeDisplayed(IWebElement e)
        {
            var _wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
            _wait.Until(x => e.Displayed);
        }```

Comment: @RichEdwards The issue was that the ExpectedConditions class is marked as obsolete because it was moved to that separate package so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this issue then here is the solution:

Use the `WebDriverWait` class from the `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI` namespace. You'll also need to get the `DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers` package from [NPM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnetseleniumextras.waithelpers/) or [Github](https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras/tree/master/src/WaitHelpers).

Then in your code you can do this:

```
// HomePageAutomatedUITests.cs
public void Arkivskaber_Open_NyArkivskaber_Modal()
{
    WebDriverWait waitDriver = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    _page.ClickArkivskaberNyButton();
    waitDriver.Until(_page.GetArkivskaberModalWaitFunc());
    string modalValue = _page.GetArkivskaberModalAttribute("class");
    Assert.Contains("show", modalValue);
}
```

In your POM (if you use those) you do this:

```
// HomePage.cs
using ExpectedConditions = SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions;
...
public Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> GetArkivskaberModalWaitFunc() => ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//div[@id='modal-window-id-here']"));
```

If you don't use a POM, then you can just make the `ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible()` call straight in your Test function. The key here is **how long you wait for the modal to appear after clicking.** If you set this too low, it might not have time to appear after you click.

Hope this helps others.